# Maximum xor among all subsets of an array

Tags: algorithm

I have to find maximum value of exclusive xor among the elements of subsets of an array. I have to check every subset of the array and the subset which will yield maximum xor will be the answer.

**For exapmle-** let **F(S)** denote the fuction which takes xor over all elements of subset **S** of array **P={1,2,3,4}**

```
F({1,2}) = 3
F({1,3}) = 2
F({1,2,3}) = 0  
F({1,4}) = 5
F({2,3}) = 1  
F({2,4}) = 6  
F({3,4}) = 7  
F({2,3,4}) = 5  
F({1,2,3,4}) = 4`
```

**Maximum of them is 7. Hence the answer is 7.***(There are other subsets but they are not worth considering).* If you are about to tell me about **Gaussian Elimination** method, I've read that somewhere on MSE but it was not at all clear to  me.
If gauss elimination is the only answer than please elaborate that to me or is there some method/algorithm I don't know of?

Comment: subset {1,2,4} = 7
doesn't it has to be considered ?

Comment: Does the elements of array P have any special property?

Comment: @justmscs no special property.

Comment: @AliAkber you can consider that too. I meant that the answer will still be 7.

Answer (score 23):

Gaussian Elimination is what you need.

For example : `3` numbers `{9, 8, 5}`

First sort them in decreasing order and convert them into binary :

```
9 : 1001
8 : 1000
5 : 0101
```

Observe the 1st number. Highest bit is 4.
Now check `4th` bit of the `1st` number (9). As it is 1, xor the number with the rest of the numbers where 4th bit is 1.

```
9 : 1001
1 : 0001 > changed
5 : 0101
```

Now check `3rd` bit of `2nd` number (1). As it is 0, check rest of the below numbers where `3rd` bit is 1.
Number 5 has 1 in `3rd` bit. Swap them :

```
9 : 1001
5 : 0101 > swapped
1 : 0001 >
```

Now xor 5 with the rest of the numbers where `3rd` bit is 1. Here none exists. So there will be no change.

Now check `2nd` bit of `3rd` number (1). As it is 0 and there is no other number below where 2nd bit is 1, so there will be no change.

Now check `1st` bit of `3rd` number (1). As it is 1, change the rest of the numbers where `1st` bit is 1.

```
8 : 1000 > changed
4 : 0100 > changed
1 : 0001
```

No more bit left to consider :)

Now xor the whole remaining array `{8 ^ 4 ^ 1} = 13`

So `13` is the solution :)

That's pretty much how you solve the problem using Gaussian Elimination :)

Here is my C++ implementation :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef long long int           ll;
typedef unsigned long long int  ull;

ull check_bit(ull N,int POS){return (N & (1ULL<<POS));}

vector<ull>v;
ull gaussian_elimination()
{
    int n=v.size();
    int ind=0;  // Array index
    for(int bit=log2(v[0]);bit>=0;bit--)
    {
        int x=ind;
        while(x<n&&check_bit(v[x],bit)==0)
          x++;
        if(x==n)
          continue; // skip if there is no number below ind where current bit is 1
        swap(v[ind],v[x]);
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(j!=ind&&check_bit(v[j],bit))
                v[j]^=v[ind];
        }
        ind++;
    }
    ull ans=v[0];
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
      ans=max(ans,ans^v[i]);
    return ans;
}
int main()
{
    int i,j,k,l,m,n,t,kase=1;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    ull x;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>x;
        v.push_back(x);
    }
    sort(v.rbegin(),v.rend());
    cout<<gaussian_elimination()<<"\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you modify it to get minimum?

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you're referring to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48682) question.

Gaussian Elimination is the algorithm description that I would expect from the math site. This is what the algorithm looks like in Python.

```
def max_xor(iterable):
    array = list(iterable)  # make it a list so that we can iterate it twice
    if not array:  # special case the empty array to avoid an empty max
        return 0
    x = 0
    while True:
        y = max(array)
        if y == 0:
            return x
        # y has the leading 1 in the array
        x = max(x, x ^ y)
        # eliminate
        array = [min(z, z ^ y) for z in array]
```

Comment: Yes, I was referring to that question. Can you tell me what is happening in this python implementation?

Comment: @johnkeets Look for the most significant one bit in the array. The max XOR has this bit set. Use XORs to set it in the max XOR and clear it in the rest of the array, then solve the smaller subproblem.

Comment: what this step is doing --> array = [min(z, z ^ y) for z in array]

Comment: @johnkeets That's clearing the most significant one bit left in the array. We do this because it's set in the max XOR and we don't want to mess it up in the future. If `a` and `b` are original array elements, then we may have new array elements like `a ^ b` and `b`. This isn't an issue because if we XOR those and get, e.g., `a ^ b ^ b`, then this is equivalent to `a`.

Comment: you are saying that if i take array as {1,2,3,4} thn i should do {1^4, 2^4, 3^4, 4}.

Comment: @johnkeets The above code does [1^4,2^4,3^4,4^4], with the 4^4 (i.e., 0) being important to keep the code moving forward.

Comment: Hi @DavidEisenstat, Thank you for your elegant solution. May I ask how to keep track of which elements has been selected to the subset?

Comment: @Ray After `array = list(iterable)` add the line `array = [(z << len(array)) | (1 << i) for (i, z) in enumerate(array)]`, which in essence adjoins an identity matrix as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Finding_the_inverse_of_a_matrix. Then at the end the indexes of the elements comprising `x` are indicated by the bottom `len(array)` bits of `x`.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, Thank you so much! WOW... This is really cool :D. I hope I fully understand it. Let's say the original array is written in a binary matrix form, A of size n-by-64(bits). The new augmented array [A | B(t)] has size of n-by-(64+n), where B(t=0) = "Identity matrix of size n". The job of B is to track if the i-th array has been xor-ed by j-th or not. So when we decide to add i into the x, we can correctly remove j if both x and i have it. Before asking this question, I had a very hard time finding a O(n) space to track this info. It seems impossible to do so... What do you think?

Comment: @Ray When the inputs are limited to 64 bits, there are at most 64 pivot elements (choice of `y`). Instead of n low-order bits, we can use 64 low-order bits in much the same way, except instead of indexing into the original array, they index into the list of pivots. Instead of adjoining an identity matrix up front, we set the appropriate bit on `y` just before reducing the rest of the array with it.