# How can I maximize XOR sum of subset of given array of integer?

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a set of integer. How can I Xor sum any subset of this given integer array,so that XOR sum is maximimum.

Example: given array {1,2,3,4} then answer is 7.

Below link provide a solution above problem but I'm seeking Dynamic programming solution.

Link:[Maximum xor among all subsets of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470592/maximum-xor-among-all-subsets-of-an-array)

I implemented a solution for above problem. Is my implementation OK?

Code:

```
//initially all index of 'dp' array is -1.

int n;//number of integer in the array

vector<int>v;//given array of integer

int dp[5002][5002];// memo. array  

int call(int i,int sum){


if(i>=n)return sum;

if(dp[i][sum] != -1)return dp[i][sum];

int profit1= v[i],profit2 = v[i];

profit1 = call(i+1,(sum xor v[i]));
profit2 = call(i+1,sum);

return dp[i][sum] = max(profit1,profit2);
}
```

Comment: sorry I'm not informed about this

Comment: Above link's solution is given in gaussian elimination algorithm.
I'm seeking Dynamic Programming solution.

Comment: Can anybody help me with come up with Dynamic problem solution?

Comment: I suggest editing the question to add the information that you need a dynamic programming solution. Also add a reference to the proposed duplicate with a note that its solution is based on Gaussian elimination which you cannot use. That will put the question in the reopen queue, and tell reviewers why it should be reopened.

Comment: Define "dynamic programming". There are certainly ways in which to interpret the term that would apply to Gauss' algorithm too. Also, whence the requirement for a particular kind of solution? That seems arbitrary

Comment: Perhaps from http://codeforces.ru/blog/entry/10229 ? I'll let other people reopen and copy the O(poly(n) 2^rank)-time algorithm from that link if they're so motivated.