# finding the value of maximum xor subarray

Tags: algorithm, max, xor

Given an array of integers (0<= A[i] <= 10^9) and (1<=i<=5*10^5), I'm trying to find the value of maximum xor subrray.
Also, if the value is smaller than the largest element of the array, then the value of that element be returned rather than the xor value.

I've tried using the kedane's algorithm for maximum subarray problem. It is failing on some test cases, I'm not able to figure out!

Is their some other approach for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum xor among all subsets of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470592/maximum-xor-among-all-subsets-of-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U must do it with the help of trie,and kadane works for maximum sum i guess, u could use dp for 10^4 case for the codechef contest problem

Answer (score -1):

This question can be done using the concept of tries. Refer to the problem no. 2 in the given link below.

[maximum subarray xor](https://threads-iiith.quora.com/Tutorial-on-Trie-and-example-problems)

Comment: Link-only answers are not welcome on StackOverflow. Please provide the necessary algorithm in the answer itself.

Comment: Actually, I just wanted to post this link in the comment section but sadly stackoverflow doesn't allow me to do so.

Comment: @TagirValeev This is not a link-only answer in the narrow sense.